# What are prerequisites and best online resources to learn everything about Lightning Network

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

**I want to learn Lightning network from basic to Advance from scratch, So what are:**

**1. Prerequisites to learn lightning network**

**2. What are best online resources to learn Lightning network from scratch**

Answer (score 7):

When I started to learn about the Lightning Network I started pretty much from 0. In particular I had pretty much no idea how Bitcoin worked. So I will argue it is possible to learn about bitcoin on the way and you can do it given a computer science or math or physics or engineering background.

As for the resources:

- [Mastering the Lightning Network](https://github.com/lnbook/lnbook/blob/develop/README.md) is available to read online
- There is a [300 pages slide deck](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Introduction_to_the_Lightning_Network_Protocol_and_the_Basics_of_Lightning_Technology_(BOLT_aka_Lightning-rfc).pdf) on which Mastering the Lightning Network heavily builds upon. A presentation of the slide deck has been recorded in 3 videos with a total runtime of 4.5 hours. [Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk1xVBv6Ilc), [Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YfQpMITUfI), and [video 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaFB_ww07rw)
- Chaincode labs made a [seminar series](https://github.com/chaincodelabs/lightning-curriculum) together with [recorded videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpLH33TRghT17_U3as2P3vHfAGL8pSOOY). Though I'd argue that the discussed protocoal stack has been superceeded by the [one presented in mastering the Lightning network](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lightning_Network_Protocol_Suite.png)
- On [my youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/renepickhardt) you find a lot of technical videos about the Lightning Network
- If you want to go really deep it makes sense to look at the [bolts repository](https://github.com/lightning/bolts) where the Lightning Network Protocol is being defined.
- Similarly you can read through the [lightning-dev mailinglist](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/lightning-dev/).
- The [Bitcoin Optech Newsletter](https://bitcoinops.org/en/newsletters/) also has a regular section about the recent progress of the Lightning Network.
- On my way I learned everything that I needed to know about bitcoin from the [Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Main_Page)
- Nowadays there are many podcasts that are mainly focused around the Lightning Network. eg: [connect the world](https://connecttheworld.live/), [lightning junkies](https://lightningjunkies.net/) or [kevin rooke](https://www.kevinrooke.com/podcast).

Last but not least my - not so secret - pro trick: Once I decided to regularly answer questions about the Lightning Network here on stack exchange I was forced to look up stuff in the bolts. So you could certainly subscribe to the `lightning-network` tag here on this site or go through the questions that have been asked and even challenge or improve the answers.